# PHP Fatal error: Class not found - PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to use [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) in a PHP project.
Here is my project structure (files are in italic font style)

- controllers

  - *Pages.php*
- tests

  - *pagesTest.php*
- vendor

  - bin

    - *phpunit.bat*
- *composer.json*

My files:

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit":"5.5.4"
    }
}
```

**Pages.php**

```
<?php
namespace controllers

class Pages
{
    public function render()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }

}
```

**pagesTest.php**

```
<?php

class PagesTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testRenderReturnsHelloWorld()
    {
        $pages = new \controllers\Pages();
        $expected = 'Hello Word';
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $pages->render());
    }
}
```

When I open the command line I write:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPUnitTestProject\vendor\bin>phpunit ../../tests/PagesTest.php
```

I receive this error message: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'controllers\Pages' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPUnitTestProject\tests\pagesTest.php on line 7`

It's a path problem. I think it's because it searches for `C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPUnitTestProject\vendor\bin\controllers\Pages()` which doesn't exists.
It should be `C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPUnitTestProject\controllers\Pages()`

Comment: This is off topic, but be sure to use file names that fulfill the [PSR-4 standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). `PageTest.php` and not `pageTest.php`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to point to the tested class, so in pagesTest.php add a require:

```
require __DIR__ . "/../controllers/Pages.php";
```

**Or** if you are using autoloading, then you can [bootstrap the autoload](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html) in your command line

```
phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php
```

**Or** you can set up a phpunit.xml configuration file like this example (from the PHPUnit page I linked to above):

```
<phpunit bootstrap="src/autoload.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="money">
      <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Which you then use with the --configuration option.

Comment: what if i have done all of the above and still get that error?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Some extra things to try...for the require, it is likely a path problem, echo out the `__DIR__` . path to make sure it is what you are thinking it is, if you are using Composer, you can run `composer dumpautoload`, or if it just seems stuck, you can delete the vendor file and run `composer update` as a desperate measure, but this will also update the dependencies.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks, turns out it was a thing to do with PHPUnit 6.0, I got it working on 5.7 (I am working on somebody else's library)

Answer (score 5):

Adding `bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"` in **phpunit.xml.dist** solved the issue for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"> <!-- in here -->
    <php>
        <!-- ... -->
    </php>
    <testsuites>
       <!-- ... -->
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `composer dump-autoload -o` command

Comment: i came here from google explicitly installed phpunit without composer

Comment: For me, even `composer dumpautoload` worked as suggested in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454285/php-fatal-error-class-not-found-phpunit#comment71846474_39455129) of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Call `phpunit` from the root folder:

```
$ cd C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPUnitTestProject\
$ vendor\bin\phpunit tests/PagesTest.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error because I hadn't named my Class the same as the filename that phpunit was calling.

e.g. I was calling:

`phpunit TEST_myweb_controller.php`

which had a class definition of: `class web_controller_test extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

This returned error: `Class 'TEST_myweb_controller.php' could not be found in '\my\path\to\tests\TEST_myweb_controller.php'`

To fix this I changed the class deinition to: `class TEST_myweb_controller extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`